# Access raw Apache webserver request

Tags: php, apache, sockets

I intend to design a web gps tracking application. the gps transmits data using TCP (no HTTP headers) on port 7070 (which I intented to change to 80). I know the protocol for communication between the GPS tracker and client, however i am stuck as i cannot intercept the datapacket on webserver.
Since application is in development stage and me being a hobbyist, I cannot afford a dedicated web host server and thus get access to php-cli interface for socket programming.

is there any way i can circumvent the need for php-cli and intercept the raw tcp packet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simply have a dedicated PHP script listening on port 7070, which you can accomplish with `fsockopen()`. You don't want to have your GPS sending directly to port 80 when Apache's already listening on port 80. Apache'll see a non-HTTP set of data come in and ignore the request completely.

```
$handle = fsockopen('localhost', 7070, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$handle) {
   die("Couldn't bind to socket (err $errno): $errstr");
}

while($data = fgets($handle)) {
    ... process gps data ...
}
```

would be the very simplest basic form of this.